# How to resolve CASE statement error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a fieldname called runTotal which is an integer.

I am trying a CASE statement that assigns values to the highest total:

`select (case when isnull(t.runtotal,90) = 0 then 'You have reached max total' else t.runtotal end) runtotal`.

I am getting following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Class is full' to data type int
```

If I remove Else t.runtotal, it works but we would like that else in the code because default value should be 90.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can fix this by casting the `runtotal` to a varchar value `cast(t.runtotal as varchar(10))` then the datatypes will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem. Below is the final solution:

```
(case when isnull(t.runtotal,9) = 0 then 'You have reached max total'
 else  str(isnull(t.runtotal,9)) end) runtotal
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are returning different data types.
The first part is returning a varchar whereas the else part returns a number.

```
select 
-- this condition returns a varchar
(case when isnull(t.runtotal,90) = 0 then 'You have reached max total' 
-- else condition is returning a number
else t.runtotal 
end) runtotal.
```

The data type of the return value should be same.
Please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is saying

```
select (case when isnull(t.runtotal,90) = 0 
   then 'You have reached max total'
   else t.runtotal end)  runtotal
```

If runTotal = 0, return me a string with a message text 'You have reach max total'.
Otherwise, return me an integer telling me the run total

This is saying, return me either an error message string, or the contents of run total converted to a string

```
select (case when isnull(t.runtotal,90) = 0 
   then 'You have reached max total'
   else Str(t.runtotal) end)  runtotal
```

Comment: All of you who have responded, I thank you very, very much.

@shahkalpesh, I don't see any difference between your solution and mine. Infact, when I ran yours, I get same error as the one I posted.

Sparky, no errors with yours but again, instead of having default value of 90 when runtotal is null, all rows are blank.

Any other ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What do you want displayed when runTotal is NULL?    You can do simply IsNull(t.runtotal,90) as RunTotal if you want to display it, but you are comparing it in your code...   Add some sample expected output and I think people will be able to clarify the SQL for you...

Comment: Yes, I can have 90 displayed when runTotal is null with isNull(t.runtotal,90) as runTotal but we want to be able to also display 'You have reached max total' when the value is 0. That's the sticking point. I am not sure who deducted 2 points. I thought they do that when your question is not clear. This question couldn't be clearer.

When app is run for the first time we, want to load value as 90 and we will continue to count down till 0. I saw something similar on this forum but it doesn't work for me.